# How to show gridview data in popup window on listbox selectionindexchanged event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events, gridview, popup

In my application , i need to show gridview data in popup div window on listbox selectionindexchanged event.. Whenever listbox selectionindex changed fired i need to show gridview data in popup div window.

I am having gridview inside the div..

When ever listbox selectionindex changed fired the gridview data should be popup..

I haven't try any code, but this is my concept.. This what am trying...but not producing output

```
$("[id*=lsitboxid]").live("SelectionIndexChanged", function () {
    $("#ShowUserProcessDOP").dialog({
        title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Anyone help me how to do this..

Comment: What have you tried? Can we see the HTML for the popup-div? Can we see the jQuery you want to run? Can we see the Method handling the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the ListBox?

Comment: Any try till now? Put some code here.

Comment: @MonikaParekh, I dint try any code am search in google regarding this concept..Please provide some links to achieve this concept

Comment: you can achieve this by using ModelPopupExtender (AjaxToolkit Control) .. please refer below link to open popup from code behind: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/215040/ModalPopupExtender-from-Server-Side-Code ......... and as Nunnerns suggested you can use SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: @NMathur, but the listbox and gridview are in different updatepanel so its not working anyother suggestions using jquery..

Comment: You have gridview on the same page? and you want to show it on the popup??

Comment: @Shekhar, Yes my gridview is on the same page within one panel and my listbox is in another panel. whenever my lisbox selection index changed fired the gridview is binding data from c# and it has to show in the popup window(i.e the gridview panel has to be popuped)

Comment: hide the panel containing the `gridview` using `css` property `dispaly:none`  and get the `html` of that pannel using `jquery` and show it on the popup. [Useful link](http://istockphp.com/demo/popup-div-with-jquery/)